# Is it possible to send an email reminder to a user x hours before a certain date using the MEVN stack?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, vue.js, email

For a school project, we're working on a web application with one of its features being signing up for a shift as a user. We're working with a Vue frontend, Node/Express backend and a MongoDB database.

One of our backlog items is a feature where users get an email reminder 2 days before their shift. This seems like a rather difficult task to me and I'm having a hard time finding any information on it online. I figured someone on StackOverflow might be able to help out. Thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So what you want to do is to set some kind of cron job - which is basically a pre scheduled task on database in use / or service. As you want to trigger a service call to check and send email you can use https://www.npmjs.com/package/node-cron to do so.

Here is a link to nice tutorial to guide you https://rajveerchoudhary8440.medium.com/how-to-schedule-email-using-cron-jobs-in-nodejs-6bcedd2b38af.

GL

Comment: Thank you! Node-cron and Nodemailer did the trick for me.